# Handle Tab Key Press on WebBrowser Control and Prevent Switching between Html Elements

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I'm working on a `WebBrowser` Control app and I need to handle <kbd>Tab</kbd> key press and prevent switching between html element. I cannot use `KeyDown` events because `WebBrowser` Control doesn't support those. So it seems I have to use `PreviewKeyDown` or something similar. Any idea on how can I program this?

Comment: @RezaAghaei To cancel Tab element switching (when you press Tab, you switch between texts on a page). I know that there are ways to do this type of stuff but I'm working with a page which only has a Flash game on it and for some reason, It keeps switching between elements that don't exist. By using, Ctrl + Tab I can always use the function of the flash game that I want. Sorry for the confusion. I just really want to make what I said on the question... And sorry for my english, I speak portuguese.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hanlde [`KeyDown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.keydown(v=vs.110).aspx) event of [`WebBrowser.Document.Body`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.body(v=vs.110).aspx) and check if the down key is <kbd>Tab</kbd> prevent default action bu setting `e.ReturnValue = false;` and perform your desired operation.

You can use [`HtmlElementEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelementeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) properties to know about pressed key and the state of the modifier keys.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com");
    //Attach a handler to DocumentCompleted
    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;
}

void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //Attach a handler to Body.KeyDown when the document completed
    webBrowser1.Document.Body.KeyDown += Body_KeyDown;
}

void Body_KeyDown(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyPressedCode==(int)Keys.Tab)
        MessageBox.Show("Tab Handled");
    //Prevent defaut behaviour
    e.ReturnValue = false;
}
```

You can also limit above code to a single element:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("someid").KeyDown += Body_KeyDown;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, dude! Great answer!

Comment: I'm sorry @RezaAghaei, but can you help me here on something about this answer you gave, I need to transform the Tab input into Ctrl Tab only when I have a boolean set to false, can you help me? I have something like this: `private void webBrowser1_PreviewKeyDown_1(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab)
            {
                toggle = !toggle;         
            }
        }` 
And I want to make Tab act like Ctrl + Tab only when I have toggle set to false, how can I do it?

Comment: @DavidAmaral You can simply send a Ctrl + Tab using `SendKeys.Send("^({TAB})");`.

Comment: Do you mean somethong like this? `if(e.KeyPressedCode==(int)Keys.Tab) && !CtrlKeyPressed && !toggle) { SendKeys.Send("^({TAB})"); e.ReturnValue = false;}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122339/discussion-between-david-amaral-and-reza-aghaei).