# Make the user's second Tab press act like Ctrl + Tab in WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to make an app where when the user presses <kbd>Tab</kbd> two times in a row, the second <kbd>Tab</kbd> should act like a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> instead.

I'm using a `toggle = !toggle` to detect the second time user presses <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Do you know how can I do this without using the `KeyDown` event (webbrowser control doesn't have those type of events) but using `PreviewKeyDown` or something similar?

It's expected behavior:

- First time user presses <kbd>Tab</kbd>, the input should be detected and go through the `WebBrowser` control (normal behavior)
- Second time user presses <kbd>Tab</kbd> should be handled and transformed into <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Comment: What about 3rd and 4th? Isn't it enough to handle `Tab` [this way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39252444/handle-tab-key-press-on-webbrowser-control-and-prevent-switching-between-html-el) and the use `SendKey` to send `Control+Tab`?

Comment: @RezaAghaei Those don't matter, only 1 and 2!

Comment: And what about 1st `Tab`? Should it be neglected?

Comment: @RezaAghaei I've tried pretty hard turning that code into something but I failed all times...

Comment: @RezaAghaei No, 1st Tab should be detected.

Comment: No problem. I'm just trying to understand desired behavior. The user may press Tab many times, so I need to know what would be expected result for 1st, 2nd, 3rd, ..... Please describe clearly what the program should do for sequence of Tabs.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Ok, I'm going to do my best: First time user presses Tab, the input should be detected and go through the webbrowser control (normal behavior), second time user presses Tab should be handled and transformed into Ctrl + Tab.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Thanks for the edit. I'll be sure to write my questions like that from now on.

Comment: Another question, What If the first time, user pressed Control + Tab?

Comment: @RezaAghaei Not a problem, that can happen.

Comment: Read the answer and expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the below example, I used `KeyDown` event of `WebBrowser.Document.Body`. And checked for <kbd>Tab</kbd> key and cached the 2nd time the user press it and changed it to a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>:

```
int i = 0;
void Body_KeyDown(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyPressedCode == (int)Keys.Tab && !e.CtrlKeyPressed)
    {
        if (i == 1)
        {
            e.ReturnValue = false;
            SendKeys.Send("^({TAB})");
            this.Text += "[C+T]";       /*Just to be obvious in title-bar for test*/
        }
        else
        {
            this.Text += "[T]";         /*Just to be obvious in title-bar for test*/
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

To test the solution, make sure you are attached event handlers [correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39252444/handle-tab-key-press-on-webbrowser-control-and-prevent-switching-between-html-el) and after the document load completed, press <kbd>Tab</kbd> more than 2 times and look at title bar of form.

The expected result of code is:

- First <kbd>Tab</kbd> press, acts normally.
- Second <kbd>Tab</kbd> press will be changed to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>
- Third and so on acts normally
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> acts normally

Note:

You will see `[T][C+T][T][T][T]...` in title bar. If you want to see `[T][C+T][T][C+T][T][C+T]...` just change the criretia to `if (i % 2 == 1)`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm going to try it and give you feedback later!

Comment: I think you got it wrong. The C+T is suppost to repeat every time Tab is pressed before. So, it's supposted to write to the title: [T][C+T][T][C+T][T][C+T][T][C+T] and so on.

Comment: No problem, but read the first and second comment under the question ;) *Those don't matter, only 1 and 2!*

Comment: Oh, my english sucks! I didn't mean that, so sorry.

Comment: No problem, just use `if (i % 2 == 1)`.